# IIS SMTP Server as MTA

Tags: iis-7, smtp, email-server

I have domain xyz.com. I'm sending mail using MTA. through Symantec Cloud.
My setup is as follows.

[Symantec Cloud]<->[MTA]<->[Local Mail domain]

all the mail out side the domain(xyz.com) goes through MTA and then through Symantec.
Out side mails are coming through Symantec Cloud then to the MTA and to the local server.

I was planning to configure IIS7 with SMTP on Windows Server 2008 as the MTA.
Is it possible to use IIS7 ?

Answer (score 0):

yes is possible, you must install the SMTP service,

start->administrative tools->server manager, go to features, select "add features", tick "smtp server"

Comment: I have installed it. but I don't know how to configure it. Do you have any good source of document on that ?

Comment: installed IIS 6 Management Compatibility and the IIS 6 Management Console must be installed for SMTP to work

Comment: I have installed IIS and SMTP service.
the problem is how to configure the mail coming from the symentec cloud (from out side domains such as gmail.com,yahoo.com) to MTA which is belong to XYZ.com and then forward to the local mail server and emails which given to the MTA by the local mail server (which is not xyz.com eg:gmail.com, yahoo.com) forward to the symantec cloud to send. 

the xyz.com's MX record is resolve as cluster10.us.messagelabs.com

Comment: with the smtp service you can send the email does not receive